# Why I can't send click in selenium python to an element?

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to send click to an element but it didn't work.

I'm using selenium in python 3.6
and the element is

```
 <a class="_m3m1c _1s3cd" href="#" role="button">Load more comments</a>
```

my code :

```
post = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_ebcx9')
comment_list = post.find_element_by_tag_name('ul')
comments = comment_list.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
```

I tried

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element_with_offset(comments[1], 5, 5).click().perform
```

even

```
ActionChains(browser).click(comments[1].find_element_by_tag_name('a')).perform()
```

What is wrong I'm doing?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have provided to send `click()` to the element you can use either of the following line of code :

- *LINK TEXT* :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("Load more comments").click()
  ```
- *XPATH* :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@role='button' and contains(.,'Load more comments')]").click()
  ```